# Unable to Pass JS variable to another PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am not a technical person, but a semi technical business man and learning/creating my own website.

I want to pass JS variables (from html page) to my another Php page. 
NOTE** I am getting redirect with required parameters in URL (title). Now, I want to pass another variables, but not through the URL

Here is my html page code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "'search_result.php' + '?title=' + dtitle",
        data: { selectedFT: "hello"}
    });
```

And my php page code:

```
<php>
$fueltype = $_GET['selectedFT'];
echo $fueltype;
// I will be using this variable as $fueltype in my further code.
?>
```

Appreciate your help. I wasted many hours to solves this through google, but nothing fits. 
Please provide me sample so that I can understand easily.

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to pass additional variables, without them showing in the address bar of the webpage. Is that correct?

Comment: If you are getting redirected - i.e. the browser opens a new page - , then this suggests the Ajax code isn't working at all. The whole point of Ajax is that the browser doesn't move to a new page. Open your browser's Developer Tools (press F12 in most browsers), run your code and then check the Console section for errors. (You may need to ensure the Preserve Log option is ticked so it doesn't reset the log when a new page is loaded)

Comment: @TimothyAlexisVass, yes this is correct.

Comment: Then you should use POST method instead of GET.

Comment: ok, thanks @TimothyAlexisVass

Answer (score 1):

Post method may help you:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            title: dtitle,
            selectedFT: "hello"
        },
        url: 'search_result.php'
    });
```

In Your PHP page add:

```
<php>
$fueltype = $_POST['selectedFT'];
echo $fueltype;
// I will be using this variable as $fueltype in my further code.
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

```
let dtitle = "Hello";
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: `search_result.php?title=${dtitle}`,
});
```

PHP file

```
<?php
   $fueltype = $_GET['title'];
   echo $fueltype;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @tavros but this is not expected. passing title works fine. Which I am passing in URL. I don't want to send variable through URL. Reason is: SEO and Passing variable will create a problem. I have many variables to pass based on several conditions and some operation which I want to perform on next page rather before passing them.

Comment: So in that case you need to use the POST method, instead of GET.